# Could not resolve host exception when calling Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())

Tags: ios, .net, dns, xamarin, upnp

So, I'm implementing uPNP in an iOS project using Xamarin and .net.  I have been struggling with getting a valid local ip address for the local device (ie. the device on which the program is running).

I've attempted to use `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`, but there is a bug in Xamarin's implementation of that method and it doesn't work.

So, I looked around and found an easy way to accomplish this.  I tried the following:

```
IPAddress[] hostAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
```

The above throws a 'Could not resolve host...' exception (where ... is my device name).

So it does get my device name, but then it cannot resolve it.

This code works just fine under windows in a WPF application.
It works just fine using Xamarin Studio on a MAC with the iPhone or iPad simulator.

However, when I try to have the MAC launch the app onto my actual iPad device I get the following exception:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Could not resolve host 'Charrison'
>   at System.Net.Dns.Error_11001 (System.String hostName) [0x00000] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/Dns.cs:298
>   at System.Net.Dns.hostent_to_IPHostEntry (System.String
>   originalHostName, System.String h_name, System.String[] h_aliases,
>   System.String[] h_addrlist) [0x00082] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/Dns.cs:326
>   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName (System.String hostName) [0x0002a] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/Dns.cs:467
>   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry (System.String hostNameOrAddress)
>   [0x00061] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/Dns.cs:406
>   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses (System.String hostNameOrAddress)
>   [0x00065] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/Dns.cs:432
>   at UpnpUI_iOS.DeviceViewController.startButton_TouchUpInside
>   (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0008c] in
>   /Users/engineering/Projects/UpnpUI_iOS/DeviceViewController.cs:83   at
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00000] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIControl.cs:30   at
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String
>   delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
>   at UpnpUI_iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in
>   /Users/engineering/Projects/UpnpUI_iOS/Main.cs:17

If anybody knows some nice and speedy way to get a valid IP address for the local device that will actually work on my iPad using .net with Xamarin, please let me know.  I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance for your useful suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stolen from Mike Bluestein in the [forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/348/acquire-device-ip-addresses-monotouch-since-ios6-0)

```
foreach (var netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {
    if (netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 ||
        netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet) {
        foreach (var addrInfo in netInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses) {
            if (addrInfo.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) {
                var ipAddress = addrInfo.Address;

                // use ipAddress as needed ...
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Xamarin has a bug in their implementation of NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().  The bug is that the interfaces that are returned in the list do not have their 'OperationalStatus' set.  They all are OperationalStatus.Unknown.  I guess it is ok to just 'assume' that the returned interfaces are 'Up' even though they say 'Unknown'?

Comment: Network.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() throws a host exception for me. I've asked about this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593642/networkinterface-getallnetworkinterfaces-call-throws-socketexception-on-iphone and would appreciate any info you might have.

Comment: While the answer seam to work fine on all 3 (iOS, Android, and UWP), on UWP it returns 169.254... address which is not a valid but MS reserved address that does not even show in ipconfig interfaces

Comment: I was using system.net.dns in my xamarin forms app and all of a sudden, iOS started throwing an exception that it could not DNS name resolve my iOS device.  This fixed that problem.

Comment: This solution (NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces) is no longer working on Android.  On my OnePlus 7T running Android 11 - netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType is always set to 0.  This used to work but recently stopped.  It appears I have to use Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()); for Android and the above solution for iOS - Kind of a pain.  I open a ticket in GitHub about the error https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/76493